# Getting a value update inside of a void in c#

Tags: c#, function, integer

My problem is that I have a value inside a c# void, but it just doesn't update, it needs to update each time the void is called but the void can't seem to get the update. Can anyone please tell me what I might've done wrong?

```
public void AddPlantages()
    {
        if(Coffee >= CoffeeToUpgrade);
        {
            Coffee -= CoffeeToUpgrade;
            Plantages++;
            DynamicPrice = 1 / Plantages;
            CoffeeToUpgrade += CoffeeToUpgrade * DynamicPrice;
            string CPP = "Price: " + CoffeeToUpgrade;
            PlantagePrice.text = CPP;

        }
```

All of the values are public Int values, its for a clicker game I am making, I just can't seem to get the values to work.

I Tried a lot of different things, I made another value (The DynamicPrice one). I thought about moving it to a different function but I realized that would raise a number of problems.
Does anyone have any ideas for what might work? Thanks!

Values of Plantages and Coffee is 0, but they increase, theres a function for increasing the value of coffee and this is the function for increasing the value of plantages.
The value of CoffeeToUpgrade is 25.

This is for a unity game btw

Comment: Small terminological note: void is the return type. You are calling a function. What are the values when you call the function? Is coffee indeed bigger or equal to CoffeeToUpgrade?

Comment: Are you sure the function is hit? Are you sure the `Coffee >= CoffeeToUpgrade` condition is met?

Comment: Take a read of https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @TimSchmelter its a unity script, i use unitys built in function to activate the function.
ive tried adding local ints inside the function, and i dont call the AddPlantages function anywhere else in the script

Answer (score 1):

You can't express fractions with `int`. If you divide 1 by 2 with `int` the result will be zero. In your code, `DynamicPrice` will be 0 if Plantages is 2 or more. Try using `double` instead of `int` for your values.

Also, if `CoffeeToUpgrade` is zero, it will never change from zero, because you would be setting it to `DynamicPrice` * 0.

```
public void AddPlantages()
    {
        if(Coffee >= CoffeeToUpgrade)
        {
            Coffee -= CoffeeToUpgrade;
            Plantages++;
            DynamicPrice = 1 / Plantages;
            CoffeeToUpgrade += CoffeeToUpgrade * DynamicPrice;
            string CPP = "Price: " + CoffeeToUpgrade;
            PlantagePrice.text = CPP;

        }
```

Comment: Oh, i completely forgot about that, thanks a lot, i think thats the problem. I forgot that integers can't have decimals.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Would you please put a breakpoint in at if(Coffee >= CoffeeToUpgrade) and update your question with the values of Coffee, CoffeeToUpgrade and Plantages at that point

Comment: The value of Coffee is 0, but since its a clicker game it increases as you click a button, the value of plantages is also 0 but theres a button that can trigger the function i wanted help with to be called that can increase plantages, and CoffeeToUpgrade is 25, the problem im having is that it doesnt really like decimals, even after i changed it to double it fails as soon as the price reaches 50, like its fine when it reaches 50 but after that it just doesnt work.

Comment: What are the values of the properties when the price is 50 and it stops working?

Comment: when the price is 50 the value of DynamicPrice changes to 0, and even when the value of Plantages increases the value of DynamicPrice still stays at 0.

Comment: To reiterate the relevant part. You have debugged the code and seen that behavior? So have gone through that method looking at DynamicPrice directly before it gets reassigned in the shown code then executed that line and looked after that at the content of DynamicPrice how it looked? WIthout that all we do is guessing not helping. Debug it!

Comment: @Ralf i have, but i think it is because that the equation creates a situation where its just to many decimals, but i think i got an idea of how to fix it tho.

Comment: @Ralf yeah my idea worked, i just had to switch around the 1 and the Plantages, so that i would avoid getting a 1/3 fraction.